# Accumulator is not adding up

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def lesser_than(alist,value):
    """
    Returns:  number of elements in alist strictly less than value
    
    Example:  lesser_than([5, 9, 1, 7], 6) returns 2
    
    Parameter alist: the list to check (WHICH SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED)
    Precondition: alist is a list of ints
    
    Parameter value:  the value to compare to the list
    Precondition:  value is an int
    """

    result = 0
    for x in alist:
        if x<=value:
            result=result+1
            return result
```

So if the x stuff in a list is smaller than the value, then I would add one to the result to see in total how many there is. But it isn't working properly. The above is my own implementation and it doesn't work and I'm not sure where it went wrong

Comment: it woul stop right after the first happening, but you need also to print the result of the function

Comment: "strictly less than" would be `x < value` not `x <= value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unindent the `return` statement, currently it will just return immediately after finding a value that is less than. Try this instead:

```
def lesser_than(alist,value):
    result = 0
    for x in alist:
        if x<=value:
            result=result+1
    return result
```

I would also make this slightly simpler with a list comprehension

```
def lesser_than(alist, value):
    return sum([x <= value for x in alist])
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use sum since the whole point is to practice for loops.

Comment: I tried the first solution and got and error saying:

The call lesser_than([5, -1, 5, 2, 5, 10, 3], 5) returned 6, not 3. 
EDIT: I just removed the equal sign and it worked! Thank you